# apt-get update stalls

Tags: 14.04, apt, updates

When I run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

the update fails to finish. This is the result in the console:

```
Get:1 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease [2,980 B]
Hit http://download.virtualbox.org trusty InRelease                                                                             
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise InRelease                                                                              
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                                                                              
Hit http://downloads.hipchat.com stable InRelease                                                                               
Hit http://download.virtualbox.org trusty/contrib amd64 Packages                                                                
Hit http://downloads.hipchat.com stable/main amd64 Packages                                                                     
Ign http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ InRelease                                                                                     
Hit http://download.virtualbox.org trusty/non-free amd64 Packages                                                               
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                                                                   
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                                                                   
Hit http://download.virtualbox.org trusty/contrib i386 Packages                                                                 
Get:2 http://repos.codelite.org saucy InRelease [2,893 B]                                                                       
Hit http://downloads.hipchat.com stable/main i386 Packages                                                                      
Ign http://repos.codelite.org saucy InRelease                                                                                   
Hit http://download.virtualbox.org trusty/non-free i386 Packages                                                                
Hit http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Release.gpg                                                                                   
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                                                                                 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                                                                 
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free amd64 Packages/DiffIndex                                                      
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Sources                                                                          
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free i386 Packages/DiffIndex                                                       
Ign http://repos.codelite.org saucy/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex                                                           
Hit http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Release                                                                                       
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                                                                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                                                                     
Ign http://repos.codelite.org saucy/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex                                                            
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                                                                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                                                                         
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam amd64 Packages                                                                   
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                                                                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                                                                          
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                                                                          
Hit http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Packages                                                                                      
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam i386 Packages                                                                    
Ign http://download.virtualbox.org trusty/contrib Translation-en_US                                                             
Ign http://download.virtualbox.org trusty/contrib Translation-en                                                                
Ign http://downloads.hipchat.com stable/main Translation-en_US                                                                  
Ign http://download.virtualbox.org trusty/non-free Translation-en_US                                                            
Ign http://download.virtualbox.org trusty/non-free Translation-en                                                               
Ign http://downloads.hipchat.com stable/main Translation-en                                                                     
Ign http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Translation-en_US                                                                             
Ign http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Translation-en                                                                                
Hit http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free amd64 Packages                                                                
Hit http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free i386 Packages                                                                 
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Translation-en_US                                                             
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Translation-en                                                                
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_US                                                                      
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                                                                      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                                                                         
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                                                                         
Hit http://repos.codelite.org saucy/universe amd64 Packages                                                                     
Hit http://repos.codelite.org saucy/universe i386 Packages                                                                      
Ign http://repos.codelite.org saucy/universe Translation-en_US                                                                  
Ign http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Translation-en_US                                                                
Ign http://repos.codelite.org saucy/universe Translation-en                                                                     
Ign http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Translation-en                                                                   
100% [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1360:8c01::19)] [Connecting to dl.google.com (2607:f8b0:4002:802::1005)]`
```

At this point it stops doing anything. I tried massing with my ppa settings, as well as my download-from location, but nothing seemed to change.

Here's what shows up when I run ifconfig:

```
ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 10:bf:48:6e:db:61  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:33721 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:33721 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:4158224 (4.1 MB)  TX bytes:4158224 (4.1 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e0:06:e6:2a:3a:bb  
      inet addr:192.168.2.23  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: 2601:0:b680:1d8:f240:a5c6:a9af:2df/128 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: fe80::e206:e6ff:fe2a:3abb/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:5214256 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:2724566 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:7298102756 (7.2 GB)  TX bytes:274205022 (274.2 MB)
```

Comment: Are you using IPv6? Pate the output of `ifconfig`.

Comment: @saiarcot895 I have added the output of ifconfig

Comment: ok, looks like Comcast is providing you with IPv6. Are you able to run `ping6 www.google.com`?

Comment: @saiarcot895 ping works. ping6 does not

Comment: Also we just set up this network so tsat could potentially be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your IPv6 connection is misconfigured, either by Ubuntu or by Comcast. As a (temporary) workaround, open up the wireless network's setitngs in Network Manager, switch to the IPv6 tab and change it from Automatic to Disabled. Disconnect and reconnect your wireless connection.

Comment: Thanks! Also, how do I know which (ubuntu or comcast) has missconfigured ipv6? @saiarcot895

Comment: That would be a bit of testing and experimentation. I would start with (with IPv6 enabled and automatically fetched) `ip -6 route` to see if there are any routing entries for the IPv6 addresses (you should see a line say something like `2601:0:b680:1d8::/64`). If that line is there, there's a better (but not certain) chance that it's something on Comcast's end. You can also use `traceroute -n ipv6.google.com` to see how far your IPv6 connection is going. Beyond that, I'm not sure.